# JAVA youtube api allow users to upload to my channel without login

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, youtube, youtube-api

I was playing around with youtube api samples that they provide in this [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/)
with **JAVA**

I can search for videos upload videos to specific channel and all the code that they provide works fine.

the only problem I face is "when I try to upload it opens my default browser and asks me to sign in"

like this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWQjb.jpg).

here is what in my head I know it's not that simple it's just a imagination of what I want to achieve.

```
// String myaccount = "username@gmail.com"
// String mypassword = "123456789"
// String mychannel_id = "UCU7mv98lde1hon2DXIgGMKg"

// signin(myaccount,mypassword,mychannel_id);
// upload(video.mp4);
```

### what I have:

```
client_id, client_secret in json file
the channel id, account, and the password
```

i was searching for about a day and all i got is ..

> access token
>    ,Token Service API 
>    ,identity toolkit api
>    ,onBehalfOfContent,onBehalfOfContentOwner

however I don't know how they work or where I can get them

finally I have small idea I traced the code and I found it saves a file with all credentials in `C://users/user-name/.oauth-credentials`
it's not readable but it seems like it is used to authorize the account with the password and channel id

can I use this?
would it expire for any reason and i have to refresh and if so how can I refresh it?

thanks for help BTW

Comment: Wait, I'm confused. Will you be shipping software that includes _your_ login credentials, so that users don't need to log in? That sounds like a horrible idea (and almost definitely a violation of your terms of use with YouTube).

Comment: my app idea is i'll use youtube to make users of my app upload videos on my channel

Comment: is it okay cause i didn't read any of terms of use of youtube

Comment: Lol, no. You clicked "accept" when you signed up. "I didn't read the agreement that I said I did" is not a valid defense.

Comment: Besides, what stops someone from using those credentials to change the password and take over the account? Sharing credentials like this is just not a good idea. Just have people sign into their account.

Comment: credentials will be coded so who is the brilliant who will guess that i'm sharing credentials in the code also he/she can't decode the binary output file so it's 0 chance for anyone to change the password and take the channel. 

but anyway i'll be more careful and read the agreement i agree to :"D
do you suggest any other platform that i can use instead of youtube

Comment: `javap -c` will expose your credentials in no time flat. As a general rule, if a person's computer can do something, that person can do it, too. After all, all of the knowledge of how to do it is on their computer (or else the computer wouldn't be able to do it). The way to handle this is to run a server and have your users upload it to you, and you then upload it to YouTube. There are security concerns there, too (and possibly legal ones, like copyright). This is all too broad for a SO question, unfortunately.